# How do you import a gradle project in eclipse?

Tags: gradle, gradle-eclipse

I have installed https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-0, which didn't change anything in the `import` dialog of eclipse (no specialized "Gradle" import option showing to select in eclipse, after the installation).

I have run `gradle eclipse` in the shell, in case that's required, then tried to import as a general existing project. A lot of compile errors that shouldn't be, after that hacky import.

This is more annoying than sbt :-)

Comment: The plugin is fairly useless. Just import the project and then run a ./gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse

Comment: It should. File -> Import... should add Gradle -> Gradle Project to the import wizard.

Comment: @aboyko then how to you specify the git URI?